# Mat Expansion pannel close on press enter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat Expansion Panel,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6kpdhy?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html

I would like to disable the feature "toggle when press enter" so I tried to add

```
(keyup.enter)="$event.stopPropagation();"
```

and

```
(keyup.enter)="$event.preventDefault();"
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try out something like this?

```
<mat-expansion-panel #matExpansionPanel (keyup.enter)="keyEnter(matExpansionPanel,$event)">
```

Ts Code:

```
keyEnter(matExpansionPanel: MatExpansionPanel) {
      matExpansionPanel.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Probably you mean prevent default?